# How I make the hidden notifications arrow point to the left in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, notifications

In Windows 7, the notification area hidden notifications arrow points to the top. I want to make it to point to the left, and make its function from Windows Vista and earlier, rather than showing hidden notifications on a little popup.

[image: Click here to see.]

Comment: If you right click on the taskbar, under properties you can tell it to show all the icons. Then you don't have to worry about the icon at all and it will be just like Windows 95. Or you could move to Windows 10 where the is changed again.